# SHA 256 Hash signing - key "XABDL..."

Tags: stellar-laboratory, security, multi-sig, key

I've just set up a SHA 256 hash as an additional signature to my account through Stellar Laboratory. I had a dry run with the testnet and I'm fairly confident it works.

Does anyone know where the hash is on the ledger? I can see I have a key "XABDL..." but I'm not sure how this is linked to the hash "0235a...".

Before anyone says, once I've used the original password I know I can't use it again and will need to revoke the weight to the hash and resecure the account.

Answer (score 1):

The "XABDL..." address you see is encoded, you can learn how to encode and decode it through [SEP-23](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0023.md), you can also [click here](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/strkey/main.go) to view the code implementation.

The following is an example written in Python that shows how to use [Stellar Python SDK](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base) to convert "XABDL..." to hex string.

```
from stellar_sdk.strkey import StrKey
hashx = "XBJCTLP7VMGH2DW7L7LWFIDFIYNOYUOXBDJUIXDH72QVC5QBK2WUAEWB"
hashx_decoded = StrKey.decode_sha256_hash(hashx)
print(hashx_decoded.hex())
# output: 5229adffab0c7d0edf5fd762a065461aec51d708d3445c67fea151760156ad40
```